# Set text to match column width in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have an image and a text in a column.
I want the text container to expand to the column width, creating a black border with the text centered.

This is what i got now.

[image]

Code.

```
List<Container> getMediaItem(List<Media> mediaItems) {
  List<Container> mediaContainers = [];
  for (Media media in mediaItems) {
    mediaContainers.add(
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            media.image,
            Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: Text(media.title),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  return mediaContainers;
}
```

If you know how to solve it please share.

Update: 
The full code (I'm trying to make a nested scroll view to display a gallery of media items, like Netflix):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Live Tree',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("LiveTree"),
              Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Column> getMediaItem(List<Media> mediaItems) {
      List<Column> mediaContainers = [];
      for (Media media in mediaItems) {
        mediaContainers.add(
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              media.image,
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
                child: Text(media.title),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      return mediaContainers;
    }

List<Widget> getCategoryRows(List<CategoryModel> categoryModels) {
      List<Widget> categoryRows = [];
      for (CategoryModel category in categoryModels) {
        final mediaItemsForCategory = getMediaItem(category.media);
        categoryRows.add(
          ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: mediaItemsForCategory,
          ),
        );
      }
      return categoryRows;
    }

    Widget gallerySection = Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: getCategoryRows(mockCategoryDataSet),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
              gallerySection,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    media.image,
    Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
      child: Text(media.title),
    ),
  ],
);
```

or

```
Column(
  children: [
    media.image,
    Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(media.title),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: MainAxisAlignment dosn't have a stretch member. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, quite sure.
The docs dosn't list it either:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html

Comment: ahh, I see you changed it to crossAxisAlignment.
That make sense.

Comment: Could you implement this in the code above?
I don't get it to work.

Comment: Not quite. I get an error stating: "BoxConstraints forces an infinite width."

Comment: Ah then it's unrelated to this code-snippet. It's the parent of the `Container` which doesn't enforce a width. I'll suggest another solution

Comment: I don't get it to work.  Perhaps the problem is outside of the scope of the original question, so I added the entire code if you have the time to take a look.

Comment: Oh yeah, you may want to replace the `ListView` with a `SingleChildScrollView` or remove the column from `gallerySection`

Comment: I did as you suggested and changed ```ListView``` to ```singleChildScrollView```, and it solved it. Thank you