# Flutter: constrain width of text in column to width of other children

Tags: flutter, layout

I'm trying to achieve this in Flutter, but just can't figure it out. It's easier to explain with a picture:

[image]

I need the text child's max width to be constrained by the other child in the column (which has a variable width - it's an `AnimatedContainer` where the width changes in an animation). How do I do that?

This is what I've got so far, but the text width is allowed to expand as far as it can go. [This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071954/set-text-to-match-column-width-in-flutter), but doesn't solve the problem - using `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` does not achieve what I need.

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    AnimatedContainer(
      width: _isSelected ? 100 : 50,
      height: 100,
    ),
    Text(
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    ),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also wrap the `Text` widget inside another `AnimatedContainer` and pass the same conditional width to it which is passed to the `AnimatedContainer` above it.

```
Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          width: _isSelected ? 100 : 50,
          height: 100,
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          width: _isSelected ? 100 : 50,
          child: Text(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore",
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: I realised I simplified my question too much! The Container is actually an AnimatedContainer, so the width changes during animation. I've updated my question. Sorry about that!

Comment: oh okay. Initially I thought too that I must be missing something here :P. I've edited the answer now.

Comment: Yes, of course! It seems really obvious now :P Been working too much without coffee lol. I did it slightly differently - I put the whole `Column` inside the `AnimatedContainer`

Comment: Great idea. Why use two when can be done with one. Things are clear now. The lack of coffee also reflected in your original question. I read it word to word about 5 times to make sure I understood the question correctly and that I'm not overlooking some detail. :D